# Which LINQ-to-MySQL implementation is most similar to LINQ-to-SQL?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I normally just use C#, DBML, MS SQL Server. Due to certain client constraints I may need to use MySQL instead, how close can I get it to being what I am familiar with?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [DBLinq](http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/) but it seems there are lots of bugs with the implementation.
I may suggest LINQ-to-[NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) 'coz it is pretty stable and actively being developed, you just need learn how to use NHibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [DBLinq](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/) for sometime,it is LINQ provider for other databases which are not supported by default linq to sql provider (like Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Ingres, SQLite, Firebird etc.). It is in very active  development, it included in Mono framework as the default Linq to Sql implementation. The release version is quit old, so I suggest you to use latest code from SVN.